# É possível "cancelar" uma função JQuery ao passar o hover?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Fiz um carrossel de imagens que passa automaticamente de 3 em 3 segundos, porém, gostaria de, quando eu passasse o mouse em cima de algum item do carrossel, parasse de scrollar.
Carrossel foi feito com um clique automático num botão que passa ele.

```
// funções que fazem o slide ser automático (o "isRight" é o botão)
function clickButton() {
  clickEvent = new CustomEvent('click');
  isRight = document.querySelector(".arrow-right")
  isRight.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
}

$.fn.extend({
  carouselRunning: (() => {
    setInterval(clickButton, 3000)
    console.log("carousel running!");
  })
});

$('html').carouselRunning();

// funções do hover
$(() => {
  $(".video-gallery").hover(
    function(){
      //atribuindo elementos com o hover
      $(this).attr('controls', 'controls'); //aqui é o hover que adicionar controls no video do carrossel
      console.log("hover");
      // aqui não sei o que fazer para parar de scrollar o carrossel.
    }
  )
});
```

Alguém já teve essa dificuldade?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Para parar o carrossel de rolar quando o mouse estiver em cima de algum item, você pode usar a função clearInterval do JavaScript. Ela permite parar uma função que foi definida com setInterval.

Você pode usar a função clearInterval da seguinte maneira:

Declare uma variável global chamada intervalId, inicializada com null. Essa variável vai armazenar o ID do intervalo que foi criado com setInterval.

No lugar de chamar a função setInterval diretamente, atribua o retorno dela à variável intervalId. Isso vai permitir que você possa usar a função clearInterval posteriormente para parar o intervalo.

```
intervalId = setInterval(clickButton, 3000);
```

Adicione um event listener de mouseenter no elemento que você quer que pare o carrossel. Quando o evento for disparado, chame a função clearInterval passando como parâmetro o ID do intervalo armazenado na variável intervalId. Isso vai parar o intervalo.

```
$(".video-gallery").mouseenter(function() {
  clearInterval(intervalId);
});
```

Adicione também um event listener de mouseleave no elemento que você adicionou o event listener de mouseenter. Quando o evento for disparado, crie um novo intervalo com setInterval e atribua o retorno à variável intervalId. Isso vai fazer com que o carrossel volte a rolar quando o mouse sair do elemento.

```
$(".video-gallery").mouseleave(function() {
  intervalId = setInterval(clickButton, 3000);
});
```

Com essas alterações, o carrossel vai parar de rolar quando o mouse estiver em cima do elemento e voltar a rolar quando o mouse sair.

Espero que isso ajude! Qualquer dúvida, só perguntar.